Stopping Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service crashes the PC
When I have to use the ryzen master tool, I  stop the "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management" and the "Hyper-V Host Compute Service".
After installing recent Windows update  KB5043076 (Sep 2024), when I stop these two services the PC crashes.
Is anyone else facing the same issue?
Without disabling the SVM mode in BIOS, is there any other workaround that anyone can think of?
No useful information in the event viewer, the events just stop abruptly and resume once the PC is rebooted.
Screenshot of event viewer - 1
Screenshot of event viewer - 2
